# How to check for 0 address with web 3

Tags: web3js, truffle

I have a method that can return data from a struct that might contain a 0 address `0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000`. Is there a way to check for this address using web 3? I know there is `web3.isAddress` but I would think this would return true for a valid address.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either do a string comparison to "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000" or make a BigNumber with it and compare it to zero.

Answer (score 3):

It's been some time since I asked this question. These days I check like this:

```
parseInt(address, 16) === 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const BLOCKCHAIN_CONSTANTS.ZERO_ADDRESS = "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000";  // somewhere in constants.js
    /**
       * @description Checks whether address is valid.
       * @param {String} address Address to check.
       * @returns {Boolean} Whether valid or not.
       */
      isValidAddress(address) {
        return this.#web3.utils.isAddress(address);
      }
    
      /**
       * @description Checks whether address is valid and not zero address.
       * @param {String} address Address to check.
       * @returns {Boolean} Whether valid non zero or not.
       */
      isValidNonZeroAddress(address) {
        if (this.isValidAddress(address)) {
          return !address.localeCompare(BLOCKCHAIN_CONSTANTS.ZERO_ADDRESS);
        }
    
        return false;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use isZeroAddress function from ethereumjs-util:

```
import { isZeroAddress } from 'ethereumjs-util';
isZeroAddress('0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000');
```

Or have your own utility functions defined somewhere in common place with Web3 utils:

```
export const ZERO_ADDRESS = '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000';
export const EATER_ADDRESS = '0x000000000000000000000000000000000000dEaD';

export const isZeroAddress = (address: string) => Web3.utils.isAddress(address) && Web3.utils.toChecksumAddress(address) === Web3.utils.toChecksumAddress(ZERO_ADDRESS);
export const isEaterAddress = (address: string) => Web3.utils.isAddress(address) && Web3.utils.toChecksumAddress(address) === Web3.utils.toChecksumAddress(EATER_ADDRESS);
```